# Flutter - Stack alignment not working vertically inside Expanded as child of Row wrapped inside a Column

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, stack, row

I am creating a custom Stepper header by using simple widgets. I need to align the line(container) between the numbers to centerRight, center and centerLeft for first, in-between and last item repsectively.

The issue is that the Stack is wrapped inside an Exapanded widget which is a child of a Row which in turn is child of a column. As long as we dont use the column, the Stack's vertical alignment works properly.

However, when I wrap the `Row` inside of a `Column`, the `Stack`'s vertical alignment just stays at the top. See the images below for the output. Currently, the Debug console give's no error or warning regarding this issue.

How can I resolve this?

Wrong Behavior:
[image: Wrong Behavior Image]

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: LayoutBuilder(
                        builder: (ctx, constraints) =>
                            Container(
                              width: constraints.maxWidth / 2.0,
                              height: 1,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Container(
                            height: 22,
                            width: 22,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11.0),
                              color: Palette.primary,
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '1'.substring(0, 1),
                                maxLines: 1,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, overflow: TextOverflow.clip),
                              ),
                            ))),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: LayoutBuilder(
                        builder: (ctx, constraints) =>
                            Container(
                              width: constraints.maxWidth,
                              height: 1,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Container(
                            height: 22,
                            width: 22,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11.0),
                              color: Palette.primary,
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '2'.substring(0, 1),
                                maxLines: 1,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, overflow: TextOverflow.clip),
                              ),
                            )))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: LayoutBuilder(
                        builder: (ctx, constraints) =>
                            Container(
                              width: constraints.maxWidth / 2.0,
                              height: 1,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Container(
                            height: 22,
                            width: 22,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11.0),
                              color: Palette.primary,
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '3'.substring(0, 1),
                                maxLines: 1,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, overflow: TextOverflow.clip),
                              ),
                            )))
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Working Solution: Here, only row exists so, the UI works fine.

Correct Image:
[image: Expected Behavior Image]

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (ctx, constraints) =>
                        Container(
                          width: constraints.maxWidth / 2.0,
                          height: 1,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Container(
                        height: 22,
                        width: 22,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11.0),
                          color: Palette.primary,
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '1'.substring(0, 1),
                            maxLines: 1,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14, overflow: TextOverflow.clip),
                          ),
                        ))),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (ctx, constraints) =>
                        Container(
                          width: constraints.maxWidth,
                          height: 1,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Container(
                        height: 22,
                        width: 22,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11.0),
                          color: Palette.primary,
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '2'.substring(0, 1),
                            maxLines: 1,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14, overflow: TextOverflow.clip),
                          ),
                        )))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (ctx, constraints) =>
                        Container(
                          width: constraints.maxWidth / 2.0,
                          height: 1,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Container(
                        height: 22,
                        width: 22,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11.0),
                          color: Palette.primary,
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '3'.substring(0, 1),
                            maxLines: 1,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14, overflow: TextOverflow.clip),
                          ),
                        )))
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better if you provide fixed height on Row, Currently using `Stack`'s `alignment: Alignment.center,` solves the issue,

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: LayoutBuilder(
                        builder: (ctx, constraints) => Container(
                          width: constraints.maxWidth / 2.0,
                          height: 1,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Container(
                            height: 22,
                            width: 22,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11.0),
                                color: Colors.cyanAccent),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '1'.substring(0, 1),
                                maxLines: 1,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, overflow: TextOverflow.clip),
                              ),
                            ))),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: LayoutBuilder(
                        builder: (ctx, constraints) => Container(
                          width: constraints.maxWidth,
                          height: 1,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Container(
                            height: 22,
                            width: 22,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11.0),
                                color: Colors.cyanAccent),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '2'.substring(0, 1),
                                maxLines: 1,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, overflow: TextOverflow.clip),
                              ),
                            )))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: LayoutBuilder(
                        builder: (ctx, constraints) => Container(
                          width: constraints.maxWidth / 2.0,
                          height: 1,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Container(
                            height: 22,
                            width: 22,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11.0),
                              color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '3'.substring(0, 1),
                                maxLines: 1,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, overflow: TextOverflow.clip),
                              ),
                            )))
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, you can try with single Stack widget providing `Alignment(x,0)` x will be -1,0 and 1

Comment: I do want the row to wrap around the content in crossAxis, which in a sense is default behavior. I have some text to go below that and need to size it accordingly.

Comment: ` CrossAxisAlignment.start` is the default one

Comment: Your solution worked as intended. So, I have accepted it. However, could you please provide some reasoning as to why the Stack's align child was not working vertically in this case when placed inside a Row which in turn is inside a column?

Comment: You can check [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)  Axis Alignment are most the necessary part. More about [ui/layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)